# Left align a logo in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, alignment

I have a little question. (sorry for my English) I want to align my app logo to the left in the ActionBar.
I don't have a back home button.
I disabled it.
But still my logo is centered, not aligned to left.

Following is for displaying my logo inside `onCreate()` in MainActivity.java

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.mylogo);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.mylogo);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

And following is for the ActionBar background color.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/OzelActionBarStili</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/OzelActionBarStili</item>
</style>

<style name="OzelActionBarStili" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>

    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>

</style>
```

And ofcourse my Activity's theme is set to AppTheme.AppBarOverlay, as you can see

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Waiting your ideas.

Comment: Why are you not using toolbar as actionbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a toolbar. An example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yourlogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yourdrawable"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

And in your manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: using actionbar will automatically adjust with activity while for toolbar you have to adjust it